# Соотнесение атрибутов таблицы БД и параметров объектов

Tags: java, реляционная-модель

Работаю над созданием веб-приложения на spring, хранящего информацию в реляционной базе данных.
Если я правильно понимаю логику связывания таблиц в рел-ой БД, то каждый объект (клиент, заказ, товар и т.д.) должны иметь уникальный id, по которому их удобно связать, в упрощенном виде это выглядят так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я понимаю, что атрибуты таблицы в БД и параметра объекта класса в java не обязательно должны совпадать? Т.е. мой класс `Order` (таблица 1) вполне может иметь поле с типом `Customer`(объект Customer имеет девять параметров, один из которых id), а вот при "связывании" java-кода с базой данных, в таблицу БД я передаю не всего клиента, а только его id. И еще, подскажите, обязательно ли класс `Customer` должен иметь параметн id или его может присвоить БД? Не могу понять разграничение функционала между базой и кодом программы.

```
public class Client {
private static int num = 1;
    private final int id;
    private String name;
    private long tel;
    private String comment;
    

    public Client (String name,long tel) {
        this.id = num++;
        this.name=name;
        this.tel=tel;
        this.comment=null;
       
    }
public class Ordering {
    private static int num = 1;
    private final int id;
    private Client client;
    private String product;
    private PriceOrder price;
  
    public Ordering(Client client, String product, int prepayment) {
        this.id = num++;
        this.client = client;
        this.product = product;
        this.price = new PriceOrder(prepayment);
    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Что вы подразумеваете под "передачей не всего клиента, а только его id"? Куда передавать и каким образом? Уточните, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Для примера не большой кусок кода.  Если я правильно понимаю механизм, то при добавлении определенных анатаций новый клиент и новый заказ будет попадать в нужную таблицу БД и храниться там.

Comment: Не очень понятен механизм передачи данных в БД, происходит ли это зеркально или я могу "приравнять" параметр обекта Заказ `private Client client` для таблицы Заказ в БД к одному атрибуту id?

Comment: И нужно ли в Java коде присваивать id клиенту, или его может сгенерировать БД?

Comment: Вопрос наверное в следующем: В jave из класса `Ordering` я могу получить всю информацию о клиенте, сделавшим заказ. А в БД из таблицы `Ordering`  я могу узнать только id, а для остальной информации мне нужно обратиться к таблице `Client`. Это верная логика для реляционной БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам необходимо посмотреть про маппинг таблиц с моделью. Маппинг в Spring можно выполнить через аннотации, в которых вы можете связать таблицы и поля, и прописать взаимодействие между ними. А потом работать уже непосредственно с объектами модели.

Более детально: [Mapping a Single Entity to Multiple Tables in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables)

Пример:

```
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"
    private Customer customer;
    
    //.....
}

@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName; 
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, думаю мне как раз для понимания не хватало строки `  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") private Customer customer;` И статью обязательно прочитаю, спасибо

Comment: Ознакомитесь ещё с hibernate, так как в Spring он используется под капотом и отвечает за работу с БД(генерация запросов, связывание, операции с БД, и.т.п.)

Comment: Спасибо, сделаю это обязательно